# Opencv How to detect 4 corners of a rectangle after applied cv::findContours and cv::drawContour

Tags: c++, opencv, rectangles, corner-detection

My problems is I want to find 4 corners of rectangles after using cvfindcontours ?
Here is my result:

image:
[image]

How can I find 4 corners of each rectangle? 
I think the building function Cv find and draw contours have their information of the corners, so how can I read it?

Comment: use minAreaRect to draw minimum bounding rectangles to these contours. Then use their vertices.

Answer (score 2):

(modified from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html))

```
// Find the rotated rectangles for each contour
vector<cv::RotatedRect> cv::minRect( contours.size() );

for( size_t = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
    minRect[i] = minAreaRect( cv::Mat(contours[i]) );
}
```

If you want the actual points on the contour, you can later find for each contour the points that is closest to each of the corners of the `RotatedRect`

Comment: This is my result after applied cv::findContours and cv::drawContour:
http://postimg.org/image/twg8sd825/32b4b9a9/
=>> how could  I find 4 corners of this rectangle?